# Opengl ES strange coordinates

Tags: c#, opengl-es

I'm trying to render basic triangle , im setting up viewport like so:

```
GL.Viewport(0, 0, (uint)Width, (uint)Height);
```

Im using vertex shader:

```
precision highp float;
attribute highp vec2 a_pos;
attribute vec3 a_col;

varying  vec3 v_col;
void main()
{
    v_col=a_col;
    gl_Position = vec4(a_pos,0,0);
}
```

and fragment shader :

```
varying highp vec3 v_col;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor  = vec4(v_col,0);
}
```

but when I try to draw using simple coordinates like

```
0,0,0
0,1,0
1,0,0
```

Whole right upper part of screen is filled.

I have to use extreme ranges of coordinates to get triangle on screen:

```
0,0,0
0,0.00000000000000000005f,0
0.00000000000000000005f,0,0
```

I dont know why. Im using C# so floats should be 32 bit like opengl es uses.
Viewport is set properly.

From my understanding I am specifying coordinates in normalized device coordinate system which spans from -1 to 1 on both axes. I don't know why is this so stretched.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out.

When I specified the last coordinate in gl_Position as 0, I made a mistake. 
Coordinates are divided by the last value as part of the opengl internal clipping process to help with perspective transformation, after changing it to

```
 gl_Position = vec4(a_pos,0.0,1.0);
```

Everything works as intended.

Comment: Note that this shader code will not compile with ES 2.0 if you use a GLSL compiler that strictly enforces the standard (which some vendors do, others do not). Integer constants are not automatically converted to float. So you have to use `0.0` wherever you currently use `0`, and `1.0` instead of `1`.